# Multiple StringReplace in CBB 10

Tags: string, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I've more than 10 different strings that I want to replace. Right now, I'm using the manual method as shown in the following code.

```
StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(
StringReplace(StringReplace(StringReplace(MyEditor->Text,
"one","ab",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"two","cd",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"three","ef",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"four","gh",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"five","ij",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"six","kl",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase),
"seven","mn",TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase);

...so on and on.
```

So, I want to know how to replace many strings using more practical and flexible method. Perhaps by using a specific function ?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTL does not have a function for that purpose.  You will have to write your own, eg:

```
struct StringReplacePattern
{
    String OldPattern;
    String NewPattern;
};

String __fastcall MultiStringReplace(const String S, const StringReplacePattern *Patterns, int NumPatterns, TReplaceFlags Flags)
{
    String Result = S;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumPatterns; ++i)
        Result = StringReplace(Result, Patterns[i].OldPattern, Patterns[i].NewPattern, Flags);
    return Result;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
StringReplacePattern patterns[] = {
    {"one", "ab"},
    {"two", "cd"},
    {"three", "ef"},
    {"four", "gh"},
    {"five", "ij"},
    {"six", "kl"},
    {"seven", "mn"},
    // and so on...
};

String S = MultiStringReplace(MyEditor->Text, patterns, ARRAYSIZE(patterns), TReplaceFlags()<< rfReplaceAll << rfIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: All the praises and thanks be to the `God`!. Like your answers beforehand, this answer is also works perfectly. You're so great, indeed. Thank you very...really much, Remy!.